# Mapeamento HIbernate Embeddable

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Bom dia !

Estou com uma dúvida com relação ao mapeamento de chaves compostas.

A situação é a seguinte:

Tenho uma classe cuja a Chave primaria da mesma é composta por duas outras classes, porém tenho uma terceira classe que chave desta terceira é uma composta da outra classe que a chave ja é composta.

A dúvida seria, utilizando embeddable eu irei referenciar a classe em si ou a sua chave?.

Exemplificando para facilitar o entendimento;

classe 1 (chave composta)
Apolice --> chave (ApolicePK embeddable)

classe 2 (chave composta)

Arquivo —> chave (é embeddable porém não sei se referencio Apolice ou ApolicePK)

Fico no aguardo de uma ajuda

Atenciosamente